# Delete specific filenames in an array using PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of PDFs and I would like to delete them. Can someone please explain to a beginner how this is done? At this point, I can do this in Excel a number of different ways but how can I simply do this in PHP?

Comment: share your code pls..

Comment: How are they stored? Do you have an array of file names or is it just a folder of pdfs?

Comment: folders of pdfs. i have a list of some of these names in excel that I would like to delete.

Comment: You want to edit excel file? And what does specific filename means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple solution:

```
<?php

    $dir = '/files_directory/';
    $files_to_delete = array('file1.pdf', 'file3.pdf', 'file4.pdf');

    foreach($files_to_delete as $file)
    {
        $file_path = $dir . $file;
        if(is_file($file_path))
        {
            unlink($file_path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want to delete the file along with the filename, so I don't think unlink is actually what I want here...?

Comment: Please explain it better, because nobody here really knows what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to search for the folder, do a loop through the files there and add some conditional statements to the loop.  If they are true or false, act on those results.

As you have not typed any code for us, I am not going to type any code back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way I could think of doing it:

```
array_map('unlink', $array_with_files_to_delete);

$array_with_files_to_keep = array_diff($list_with_pdfs, $array_with_files_to_delete);
```

Comment: "Delete" might also mean using the `unlink()` function, but before doing that one should read the manual page, to know what it does ;-)

Comment: i want to delete the file along with the filename, so I don't think unlink is actually what I want here...